# Stuck in boot after encrypting

Tags: boot, encryption, disk-encryption

```
Device Name: Lenovo K3 Note 
OS: Lineage OS 14.1 (Android 7.1)
Recovery: CWM ; Accessible
Bootloader Status: Unlocked and Accessible
Root Status: Rooted
Accessible via adb
```

I used the Android's `Encrypt Device` option to Encrypt my device. The Encryption Process went smoothly with no errors. The device then rebooted and asked for pattern. After I entered the pattern, the device starts booting but never completes booting. While it is stuck in the boot animation, it is accessible via `adb`. I can also access the recovery and bootloader via `adb reboot recovery` and `adb reboot bootloader`.

I tried clearing `cache` and `dalvik`. Both proved of no use as the problem persists. The only app that I can think that might be interfering is `SnooperStopper`. I however can not uninstall it via `adb` as it is a Device Administrator.

Is there a way to either decrypt my device via adb or to boot it successfully.

**EDIT:** I found that there is a missing link from `/mnt/user/0/primary -> /data/media/0/` which broke the symlinks `/sdcard/` and `/storage/self/primary/`. Manually creating the symlinks however proved of no use nor did adding them to start-up by adding the command to `/data/local/userinit.sh` which was called by `/etc/init.d/90userinit`.

Comment: You will almost certainly need to wipe the device and start over.

Comment: I added an edit. Maybe that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally ended up wiping my device and then restoring from a backup.